# PHP MySQL: Fetching all associated rows from multiple tables using one query?

Tags: php, mysql, join, array-merge

For a recipe app I've got one table storing general recipe info and an id. I've then got several other tables tables storing associated data like ingredients, instructions, notes and so on. At the moment I'm fetching and connecting all this data using multiple simple SQL statements.

However I now need to put the entire result (everything relating to one recipe, via its "recipe_id") into one single array so that I can manipulate it as one entity.

I first tried `array_merge` but then got on using JOINs but I'm not certain that they do what I like. Is that the route I need to take of are there other options?

Here is my current code:

```
$conn = connDB();
    // Get basic recipe data
    $sql = "SELECT recipe_id, date_created, name, description, author, cooktime, preptime, totaltime, yield, category_id, cuisine_id, image, image_url, url FROM recipes WHERE recipe_id=" . $recipe_id . " LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // Check that we get a result - ie a valid recipe_id
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $basicrow = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

        // Get ingredients
        $sql = "SELECT recipe_id, ingredient_id, ingredient, uom_id, ingredient_quant FROM ingredients WHERE recipe_id=" . $recipe_id . "";
        $ingredientresult = $conn->query($sql);
        $ingredientrow = $ingredientresult->fetch_assoc();  

        // Get Units Of Measurements
        $sql = "SELECT uom_id, uom_long, uom_short FROM uom";
        $uomresult = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($uomresult->num_rows > 0) {
            $uomArray = array();
            while($uomrow = $uomresult->fetch_assoc()) {
                $uomArray[$uomrow['uom_id']]["uom_id"] = $uomrow['uom_id'];
                $uomArray[$uomrow['uom_id']]["uom_long"] = $uomrow['uom_long'];
                $uomArray[$uomrow['uom_id']]["uom_short"] = $uomrow['uom_short'];
            }
        }

        // Get instructions
        $sql = "SELECT recipe_id, instruction_id, instruction FROM instructions WHERE recipe_id=" . $recipe_id . "";
        $instructionresult = $conn->query($sql);

        // Get notes
        $sql = "SELECT recipe_id, date_created, note FROM notes WHERE recipe_id=" . $recipe_id . "";
        $notesresult = $conn->query($sql);

    } else {
        echo "No such recipe"; // Not a valid recipe_id
    }

    $conn->close();
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of table joins my friend?

Comment: @Matt The question says "then got on using JOINs but I'm not certain that they do what I like" so apparently he has.

Comment: `JOIN` is indeed the way to do it. If they don't do what you like, then you're probably not doing it correctly. But since you haven't shown what you tried, there's no way to help you correct it.

Comment: Your code only allows for one ingredient in the recipe. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: If you combine all the queries into a single join, you're going to get lots of repeated results, because a join creates a cross product. So if a recipe has 5 ingredients and 3 notes, you'll get 15 rows, one for each combination of ingredients and notes.

Comment: You really should use join here. Provide us your current code for joins and we'll help you correct it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes precisely. And it's because I couldn't find a way around all those repeated results I gave op JOINs.

Comment: And `$ingredientrow` holds the result for all the ingredients.

Comment: You could combine the `recipe` and `ingredients` queries with a join, and then use separate queries for the instructions and notes.

Comment: How can one ingredient row hold the result for all the ingredients?

Comment: @Barmar You are right - I'm resusing `$ingredientresult` elsewhere in the code to do a loop. So that fetch_assoc line doesn't actually do anything here and should be taken out. Thanks for pointing that out and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Barmar If I join `recipe` and `ingredients` I still have to loop through all results to create my final array as per thomas_lrd's answer below though right?

Comment: Of course. The point of doing joins is to reduce the number of queries you make against the DB, you still have to loop through everything to get all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could create associative arrays keyed off of recipe id, then you could loop through them and combine the information in the form you want.  Using joins is the best way to get this data in one array.  The only caveat I have with this is how long it takes the queries to run.  I have personally used both approaches, it all depends on what I'm trying to do, and how long it takes the page in question to load.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea that i'm toying with now. Taking the result set arrays I have now (that already gets the data I want) and looping through them creating the nested array that I need for the next step.

Comment: Wouldn't using a JOIN create a lot of duplicate results for a query like this (as discussed above)? Each recipe could have many ingredients or few. Many instructions or none and so on.

Comment: A join shouldn't create anybody's records. It might duplicate data.  Ie the name of the recipe.  But that should be easy to deal with.